# Trigger Snowflake task when data pushed to Snowflake stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 1 snowflake internal stage where I am pushing json files data through snowsql. Then I will run some queries using snowflake UI. Currently its all manual, is there anyway we can trigger snowflake task when I put data on the stage?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to trigger a Snowflake task, only schedule it. You ***can*** however prevent the running of a task on a particular schedule based on a condition. Right now, the only condition that is supported is SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_stream_has_data.html

In any case, you don't need tasks to automate this pipeline. Using streams and tasks is more than is required for this flow. If the Snowflake stage is external (S3, Azure Blob, GCP storage rather than a Snowflake internal stage) you can use Snowpipe to copy newly arriving files into a table.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe.html

Comment: thanks for the comment. But I have an internal stage, what can we do in this scenario?

Comment: Snowflake supports internal stages with Snowpipe, but it does not support auto-ingest. You'd need to run `alter pipe mypipe refresh` to ingest the most recent file arrivals. It will automatically keep track of new files and files it's already ingested as long as you run refresh at least once a week. You can put that on a task to make sure it happens at least once a week, and then you can do on demand when you load new files.